# Cygwin bash: read file word by word

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, cygwin

I want to read text file word by word. Problem: there are some words containing "/*". Such a word causes script to return files in root directory. I tried:

```
for word in $(< file)
do
    printf "[%s]\n" "$word"
done
```

And several other combinations with echo/cat/etc...
For this file:

```
/* example file
```

I get following output:

```
[/bin]
[/cygdrive]
[/Cygwin.bat]
...
[example]
[file]
```

Should be easy but it's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn off pathname expansion globbing. Run a new shell with `bash -f` and try again. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs or dive into the manpage with `man bash`, maybe do `man bash | col -b >bash.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this solution, the double quotes around `$(< file)` stop `*` from being expanded and `sed` is used format the output as required:

```
for word in "$(< file)" 
do
    echo "$word" | sed -E 's/(\S*)(\s)/[\1]\2\n/g'
done
```

Output:

```
[/*] 
[example] 
[file]
```

Answer (score 0):

this may help;

```
# skip blank lines and comment lines begining with hash (#)

cat $CONFIG_FILE | while read LINE
  do
  first_char=`echo $LINE | cut -c1-1`
  if [ "${first_char}" = "#" ] 
   then
      echo "Skip line with first_char=  >>${first_char}<<"
   else
     :
     echo "process line:  $LINE"  ;
   fi

done
```

Another way is to use a case statement

Comment: Useless use of cat spotted!

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
while read -a a; do printf '[%s]\n' "${a[@]}"; done < file
```

Output:

```
[/*]
[example]
[file]
```